# Courant Bracket

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Let P be a manifold and D be a subbundle of
${TP} $ :=TP⊕T*P ,then how can one prove that Γ(D) ,sections of D,  is closed under the Courant bracket? By courant bracket I mean $[[(X,α),(Y,β)]]=([X,Y],(L_Xβ− L_Yα -d(α(Y))$?

Comment: Are you following a reference?

Comment: Yes,the main reference is "Dirac Manifolds" by: Courant.

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1990-0998124-1

Comment: On which page is the claim made?

Comment: page 645/ def. 2.3.1

Comment: The claim in the question body (v2) is not true for general $D$.

Comment: Would you please explain more? My question is about "definition 2.3.1" , I mean Dirac bundle. I want to know that what does "closed under Courant Bracket" mean? I know what being closed means, in fact I want to write a proof for it.      Thanks.

Comment: You're right! I find a counter example.